# ffmpeg settings for converting to mp4 from ogg for HTML5 video

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video

I'm trying to convert OVG to MP4 H.264 valid format for use in HTML5 video.
I tryid this:

```
ffmpeg -i video_source_file.ogv -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -b 250k -bt 50k -acodec libfaac -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 video_out_file.mp4
```

But the generated format is invalid for Internet Explorer 9 and 10. Other H.264 videos works fine. VLC says that the generated video is H.264.

It only happens when I try to convert ogv/ogg valid videos to mp4 H.264.

I also tried many options in ffmpeg2theora, but it appears only to convert files to theora. I thought this might help, but I could not generate a valid H.264.

How to make it work?

Comment: Complete ffmpeg console output is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to work:

> ffmpeg.exe -y -i in.ogv -vcodec libx264 -vpre libx264-lossless_max out.mp4

Comment: ,any suggestions about how to do this in reverse?  From an h.264 file that is suitable for streaming from Wowza to iOS devices?